# Is it possible to create a hierarchy of Session instances in AlamoFire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Say I have a interceptor which adds a UserAgent, I want this on all my requests, even the non authenticated ones. So I create a

```
let baseSession = Session(interceptors: [UserAgentInterceptor()]
```

Now I need authenticated requests within logged in part, so I create

```
let userSession = Session(intercetors: [AccessTokensInterceptor()]
```

Now obviously userSession doesnt add a user agent.
Is it possible to do something like okhttp does, in that you can create a new session instance, which is a shallow copy of the parent one? Something like this?

```
let userSession = Session(parent: baseSession, interceptors: [AccessTokensInterceptor()]
```

where now user session would inherit all the config stuff of the base one?

Obviously I know I can just add UserAgentInterceptor to the user session my self, but in the real project its bit more involved and multiple levels of such hierarchy

Is this possible? I though its what `delegate` was for, but it doesn't seem so

Answer (score 0):

No. Alamofire is not designed to be used this way, nor is it recommended. In your particular instance, it's not necessary to use an adapter to add a `User-Agent` (and Alamofire already adds one), as you can set such headers at the `URLSessionConfiguration` level. Fundamentally, Alamofire works like `URLSession`, since that's what Alamofire's `Session` used internally.

If you need to apply interceptors to less than 100% of the requests made by a `Session`, the simplest way may just be to apply them to the requests directly. When you make a `request`, you can pass whichever interceptors you want to it. For example:

```swift
AF.request(urlRequest, interceptor: SomeInterceptor())...
```

Comment: Well user agent is just an example to illustrate. I'm trying to create a sort of internal library, so a feature developer doesn't need to worry about attaching access tokens and what not, just pick a correct Session instance to inject.

By not being design, you mean its not good to have multiple instances of Session? Does it multiply the threadpools?